# automatic update of attachment in Trello

Tags: trello

After adding an attachment in trello how is it possible to have it automatically updated when changes are made to the original word document on your computer?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to make a document update itself after uploading is to attach a Google Document by selecting "Google Drive" The attachment is basically a link to the Google Document, and all edits made there are online.

Attaching a Word Document (.doc or .docx) means you are uploading a file, and there is no dynamic editing functionality once you upload the file itself.